# Routing more than one action to the same controller and action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, match

I am trying to get something like this working on my Rails app:

```
match '/:language', :to => 'posts#search_result'
match '/:tag', :to => 'posts#search_result'
match '/:language/:tag', :to => 'posts#search_result'
```

I am using this search_result action to filter some posts depending of the language and the tag.

The problem is that sometimes :tag will be nil or :language will be nil; so i have these 3 possibilities when calling the action:

```
<%=link_to "Spanish", {:controller => 'posts', :action => 'search_result', :language => "spanish"} %>

<%= link_to "Spanish", {:controller => 'posts', :action => 'search_result', :language => "spanish", :tag => @tag} %>

<%=link_to "#{tag.name}", {:controller => 'posts', :action => 'search_result', :tag => @tag} %>
```

And I am expection to have URLs like:

```
/spanish          (for the first case)
/spanish/rails    (where rails is a tag, for the second case)
/rails            (for the third case)
```

But right now i am getting the rigth thing for the first and third case, but for the second case i am getting: 
**/spanish?tag=rails**
or again **/spanish** (depending on if i had selected a tag first or a language first).

I hope i explained myself right. Any idea??. thanks!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The router cannot tell the difference between a :language and a :tag.

Just because your routes say "language" and "tag" when you are constructing your code in the view.. remember that in the html this has been translated into just plain ole URLs  eg /spanish or /rails

the route then has to be figured out from this URL.

Now as I said, the router can't tell that a particular word *is* a language or a tag... and the plain-ole-URL doesn't have the word "tag" or "language" in it anymore... so your two routes here:

```
match '/:language', :to => 'posts#search_result'
match '/:tag', :to => 'posts#search_result'
```

are both the *same* kind of URL

Just a single token after the slash. Here are some examples that will match that route:

```
/greek
/spanish
/rails
/urdu
/whatever
```

They will *all* match the first route that matches on "a single token after a slash"... which means your router will match all of them to the "language" route and will never ever match the "/:tag" route, because it's already matched on the route above.

he he: it's all greek to the router ;)

**Edit:**

> Hi, this is helping me a lot to understand how routing works.. but still i can't see it clear. I understand what you said, and so basically i understand i should do something like match '/tags/:tag to at least only route to posts#search_result the URLS starting by /tag .. what would be a solution??

yes, "/tags/:tag" would be clear and unambiguous, but if you want it to truly flexible in tag vs language you would be better served by the simple:

```
match '/posts/search', :to => 'posts#search_result'
```

which can use any of your link_to examples above to generate eg:

```
/posts/search?tag=rails
/posts/search?language=spanish
/posts/search?language=spanish&tag=rails
```

It's also far more clear what is being passed and *why*.

The description of the third URL is "I'm searching for a set of posts which have language = spanish and tag = rails"

Your URL should reflect the *resource* (which in this case is a set of posts) everything else is better done as query params.

Comment: Hi, this is helping me a lot to understand how routing works.. but still i can't see it clear. I understand what you said, and so basically i understand i should do something like `match '/tags/:tag` to at least only route to posts#search_result the URLS starting by /tag .. what would be a solution?? And if the router don't make different between :language and :tag why this two lines give different behaviour?: `match '/:language(/:tag)', :to => 'posts#search_result'` and `match '/:tag(/:language)', :to => 'posts#search_result'`

Comment: have added to my answer to reflect a better solution. I don't know why the latter two behave differently - but in the end, it shouldn't matter - they're not the best/most explanatory choice for the routes you need.

Comment: Can you tell me what the different behaviour is for your two new examples?

Comment: Of course: with `match '/:language(/:tag)'` I got an error like this: `No route matches {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"search_result", :tag=>"Poems"}`; and with `match '/:tag(/:language)', :to => 'posts#search_result'` i got a error in a different part of the code telling: `No route matches {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"search_result", :language=>"espanhol"}`     You can see that in the first case i am doing a link_to with :tag parameter and it doesn't like the /:language  and in the second case i am doing a link_to with :language parameter and it doesn't like the /:tag at the beggining.

Comment: Besides this, i like your solution and its working almost perfect.. for some reason if i first filter by language then and then i click on a tag i get `/search?tag=rails` istead of `/search?tag=rails&language=spanish`. And i think it is related with routing cause the combination of the two lines i wrote in my last comment i got working any combination (but gives issues with other routes and i know is not the right solution.

Comment: hey, everything is fine now, your solution worked perfectly.. the thing i commented before was a mistake in one of my links!... all clear now :) thanks a lot!.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of defining /:language and /:language/:tag separately, define them together, with /:tag as an optional URI element.

```
match '/:language(/:tag)', :to => 'posts#search_result'
```

I believe routes are matched (and URIs generated from them) in the order that the routes are defined. You defined /:lang before you defined /:lang/:tag, so it matched /:lang and made :tag a GET parameter. I suppose you could optimize the ordering of your definitions, but I believe using the above syntax is the preferred method.

Comment: With `match '/:language(/:tag)', :to => 'posts#search_result'` I had issues when i first selected a tag. But it was the way to go cause with the two lines: `match '/:language(/:tag)', :to => 'posts#search_result'` and `match '/:tag(/:language)', :to => 'posts#search_result'` I covered all the cases and worked perfectly. Wouldn't find it without your help. thanks.
`